# limit variable information preprocessing in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, graph

I have a project which I am working on that involves a Vertex-Vertex data structure, which is for all purposes just a graph.  Each node has pointers to each of it's neighbours, which leads to many cycles, since I'm using it to represent a mesh.

The problem I'm having is that when debugging, if I want to see a node's information, VS 2010 will spend the next 5-10 minutes generating the information for the variable.  I'm pretty confident it is related to the large number of cycles.  Is there a way to only generate the info on demand.  As in - only show/generate the immediate information needed?

So if I click on a node, I don't want visual studio to spend the next 5-10 minutes making the entire graph structure following every pointer, just so I can see who the immediate neighbours are of a node.  Then when I click on a different node, show me those immediate neighbours.

Thanks 
Adam.

Comment: Hmm, you could pull up the immediate window and punch in exactly what you want to see, then it should only evaluate that one thing.  You can also put the same expression in to the watch dialog.

Comment: If I type the variable name into the immediate window, the same thing happens, it lists all of its members and calculates all of their members ...

Comment: I removed the C++ tag as it's orthogonal to the question being asked (about the debugger).

Comment: Yeah but you can put entire expressions in the immediate window, i.e. variableName.member.member